# Where to place scripts

Tags: php, joomla

I´ve these scripts:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/jquery.qtip.css" />
<?php $verbindung = mysql_connect ("localhost", "XXXX", "XXXXX") or die ("keine Verbindung möglich. Benutzername oder Passwort sind falsch"); mysql_select_db("XXXXXXX") or die ("Die Datenbank existiert nicht."); ?>
<?php
$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM dbtest";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis);
$Name=$row->Name;
$Bech=$row->Beschreibung;
?>
```

I´m using Joomla. At the moment i need to copy them in every single article, where i want to use them. Where can i add them, so that they´re automatically loaded on every content page?

Comment: Look for a `header.php` file and place them with the other external script files.

Comment: How safe is it to put this code in the head?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what your Joomla theme / template looks like, I cannot answer that. My biggest concern would be the vanilla variable names as they might conflict with something in the big picture. Also, try and place the script link AFTER any others.

Comment: Creating a plugin would be a good idea. Don't use `msql_connect`! Use proper Joomla coding standards unless it's a separate database table, in which case, use msqli

Comment: I suggest that you create a plugin to add your code in every article here is a useful link : http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_content_plugin

Answer (score -1):

I would use for small queries of internal or external database a sql-query-module, there are some at the JED. And then use it in content articles with the loadmodule syntax.
If you wanna connect to external db, better look for a MVC variant, a plugin or component. It is not safe to put such code to the head or directly at the content.